# Drupella File Manager for uploading a file. need create folder feature in d9

Tags: file-management, file-manipulation, responsive-filemanager

I have used Drupella File Manager for uploading a file ..but i need create folder feature also in this contrib module iam using it for drupal 9 is there any way to add this feature can anyone please give me an idea

i need create folder feature along with file handling create read update delete files and folders